# Constrained portfolio optimization in R

Tags: r, optimization, portfolio

I have the following values:

```
ReturnVec <- c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3)
StandardDev <- 0.4
```

I want to find the portfolio weights which optimizes the value:

```
Weights <- c(rep(1,n)) #specifying a starting value in each weights
SR <- (t(Weights)%*%ReturnVec)/0.4 #needs to be maximized, by changing weights
```

The weights must sum to 1, and no weights are allowed to be negative.

So basically I would just need to find the weights which maximizes the Sharpe ratio of a portfolio with a given portfolio variance with respect to the two constraints.

Can anybody help me out here? As you can probably extract from this I am no expert in R.

Comment: I believe you are trying to solve a linear programming problem. Check out the `lpsolver` package and see if you can work with that (I'm a little busy but may return later with a better written up solution)

Comment: Thank you - I will check the lpsolver out and see if I can work my way around it. If you have time later on I would love a written up solution :)